# How can I get this simple (IBM MQ) MDB project to deploy to Tomee... -what configuration is required for a successful deployment

Tags: cdi, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean, java-10, tomee-7

QUESTION:

What CDI annotations, tomee.xml configuration [,etc.] will allow successful deployment of this simple message driven bean?

---

I'm attempting to deploy a MessageDriven bean using **CDI** and IBM MQ - running on Tomee 7.1 Plume...

After many iterations,  I am still at a loss as to how to overcome the Exception below and would appreciate some help/guidance.

***--Are my "ActivationConfigProperty" values (in the "ChatBean" mdb example) correct, based on the tomee.xml file?***

**Exception**

```
    -
    -
    -         
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.427 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.logAutoCreateResource Auto-creating a Resource with id 'DEV.QUEUE.1' of type 'javax.jms.Queue for 'ChatBean'.
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.427 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=DEV.QUEUE.1)
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.432 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.432 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.createContainer Auto-creating a container for bean SimpleMDB.Comp263849086: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.432 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.437 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.core.managed.SimplePassivater.init Using directory /usr/local/tomee/temp for stateful session passivation
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.445 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'java:comp/env/imq_qcf' in bean SimpleMDB.Comp263849086 to Resource(id=imq_qcf)
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.445 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceEnvRef Auto-linking resource-env-ref 'java:comp/env/imq.baq' in bean SimpleMDB.Comp263849086 to Resource(id=imq.baq)
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.449 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "/usr/local/tomee/webapps/SimpleMDB" loaded.
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.449 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/SimpleMDB
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.471 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=ChatBean) --> Ejb(deployment-id=ChatBean)
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.489 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initSingleton Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@340b9973
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.554 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.557 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader.startUp Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.699 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints All injection points were validated successfully.
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.703 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 149 ms.
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.838 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/SimpleMDB
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.841 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
    -
    -
    -
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.926 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SimpleMDB]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/SimpleMDB: Error deploying 'ChatBean'.  Exception: class org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection. An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection. An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.
            at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1315)
            at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
            at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            ... 10 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/SimpleMDB: Error deploying 'ChatBean'.  Exception: class org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection. An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection. An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.
            at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1096)
            at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:757)
            at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1303)
            ... 15 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Error deploying 'ChatBean'.  Exception: class org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection. An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection. An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.
            at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs(Assembler.java:1686)
            at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:997)
            ... 17 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection. An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.
            at org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer.deploy(MdbContainer.java:250)
            at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs(Assembler.java:1673)
            ... 18 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection. An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
            at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:174)
            at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:135)
            at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:394)
            at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.acquireConnection(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:289)
            at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.<init>(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:229)
            at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:558)
            at org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer$MdbActivationContext.start(MdbContainer.java:641)
            at org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer.deploy(MdbContainer.java:232)
            ... 19 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
    The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
    See the linked exception for further information.
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
            at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
            at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
            at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:172)
            at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
            at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:98)
            at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)
            at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:104)
            at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:268)
            ... 24 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.<init>(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment, int)],3=Class.getConstructor0]
            at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:831)
            at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:676)
            at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:164)
            ... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.<init>(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment, int)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3302)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2110)
            at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:738)
            ... 31 more

    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.926 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/SimpleMDB.war]
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SimpleMDB]]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.927 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/SimpleMDB.war] has finished in [1,926] ms
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.927 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT]
    11-Oct-2018 19:20:27.928 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /
    -
    -
    -
```

Note, my example (CDI annotated) MDB was derived from this link:

```
    http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-mdb-and-cdi/
```

*...Unfortunately (for me) I could not locate the tomee.xml or resources.xml upon which the example - "simple-mdb-and-cdi" - annotations are based...*

**conf/tomee.xml**

```
    <tomee>

        <Container id="imq_container" type="MESSAGE">
            ResourceAdapter=imq_ra
            MessageListenerInterface=javax.jms.MessageListener
            ActivationSpecClass=com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl
        </Container>

        <Resource id="imq_ra" type="com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl">
            connectionConcurrency=5
            maxConnections=10
            logWriterEnabled=false
            reconnectionRetryCount=5
            reconnectionRetryInterval=300000
            traceEnabled=false
            traceLevel=3
        </Resource>

        <Resource id="imq_qcf" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl">
            TransactionSupport=none
            ResourceAdapter=imq_ra
            HostName=172.17.0.3
            Port=1414
            QueueManager=QM1
            Channel=DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
            TransportType=CLIENT
            UserName=admin
            Password=passw0rd
        </Resource>

        <Resource id="imq_container-javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl">
            TransactionSupport=xa
            ResourceAdapter=imq_ra
        </Resource>

        <Resource id="imq.bar" type="javax.jms.Queue" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy">
            arbitraryProperties
            baseQueueManagerName=QM1
            baseQueueName=DEV.QUEUE.1
            CCSID=1208
            encoding=NATIVE
            expiry=APP
            failIfQuiesce=true
            persistence=APP
            priority=APP
            readAheadClosePolicy=ALL
            targetClient=JMS
        </Resource>

        <Resource id="imq.baq" type="javax.jms.Queue" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy">
            arbitraryProperties
            baseQueueManagerName=QM1
            baseQueueName=DEV.QUEUE.2
            CCSID=1208
            encoding=NATIVE
            expiry=APP
            failIfQuiesce=true
            persistence=APP
            priority=APP
            readAheadClosePolicy=ALL
            targetClient=JMS
        </Resource>        

    </tomee>
```

**ChatBean.java**

package org.superbiz.mdb;

```
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
    import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import javax.jms.Connection;
    import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
    import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
    import javax.jms.JMSException;
    import javax.jms.Message;
    import javax.jms.MessageListener;
    import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
    import javax.jms.Queue;
    import javax.jms.Session;
    import javax.jms.TextMessage;

    @MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "DEV.QUEUE.1"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
    })
    public class ChatBean implements MessageListener {

        @Resource(name = "java:comp/env/imq_qcf")
        private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

        @Resource(name = "java:comp/env/imq.baq")
        private Queue answerQueue;

        @Inject
        private ChatRespondCreator responder;

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            final TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            final String question = textMessage.getText();
            respond("...the question was: " + question);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        }

        private void respond(String text) throws JMSException {

        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;

        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create a Session
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(answerQueue);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

            // Create a message
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

            // Tell the producer to send the message
            producer.send(message);
        } finally {
            // Clean up
            if (session != null) {
            session.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

**src/main/resources/beans.xml**

```
    <beans/>
```

**IBM MQ 9.1 jars were extracted from wmq.jmsra-9.1.0.0.rar, and added to tomee/lib folder (as per:  tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-webspheremq.html)**

```
    bcpkix-jdk15on.jar
    bcprov-jdk15on.jar
    com.ibm.mq.connector.jar
    com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
    com.ibm.mq.jar
    com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
    com.ibm.mqjms.jar
    com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
        <artifactId>SimpleMDB</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
            <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd.HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>8.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>    
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
                <version>9.1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
                <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>10</release>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <executable>/usr/local/jdkv10/bin/javac</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Tomee-Application-Version>${project.version}-${timestamp}</Tomee-Application-Version>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

***FWIW, to provide some more context: the "sendMessage" and "receiveMessage" methods in this stateless bean (below) work fine with the tomee.xml configuration and the tomee/lib MQ jars.***

*the issues seems to be related (indirectly?) to the CDI annotations/"wiring" of the message driven bean(MDB)... I though that perhaps my annotations may be improperly wired to the tomee.xml configuration(?)*

```
    package org.superbiz.mdb;

    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.jms.Connection;
    import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
    import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
    import javax.jms.JMSException;
    import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
    import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
    import javax.jms.Queue;
    import javax.jms.Session;
    import javax.jms.TextMessage;

    @Stateless
    public class Messages {

        @Resource(name = "imq_qcf")
        private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;    


        @Resource(name = "imq.bar")
        private Queue devQueue1;    


        public void sendMessage(String text) throws JMSException {

        System.out.println("\n\n...........................Messages/sendMessage............................\n\n");

        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;

        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create a Session
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(devQueue1);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

            // Create a message
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

            // Tell the producer to send the message
            producer.send(message);
        } finally {
            // Clean up
            if (session != null) session.close();
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }
        }

        public String receiveMessage() throws JMSException {

        System.out.println("\n\n...........................Messages/receiveMessage............................\n\n");        

        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            // Create a Session
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            consumer = session.createConsumer(devQueue1);

            // Wait for a message
            TextMessage message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);

            return message.getText();
        } finally {
            if (consumer != null) consumer.close();
            if (session != null) session.close();
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }
        }
    }
```

**Environment:**

```
Java 10
IBM MQ Version 9.0
Tomee 7.1.0 Plume
```

Comment: The rar file is meant to be a bundled Resource Adapter Ra.  It looks like the following page documents how to use a RA with TomEE, I would suggest you do that: [Changing JMS Implementations](http://tomee.apache.org/changing-jms-implementations.html)

Comment: If you don't want to use the rar in it's intended way and instead just just jar files I would suggest you go google MQC91, find the link for IBM MQ V9.1 LTS Clients, this will take you to IBM Fix Central (you need to login with a IBM ID, if you don't have one, creating one is free).  Then get the 9.1.0.0-IBM-MQ-Install-Java-All , this will come as a self extracting jar file just run it as `java -jar 9.1.0.0-IBM-MQ-Install-Java-All.jar`.  The jar files extracted should be placed in your class path.  I would still recommend the rar path described in the link I provided.

Comment: Thank you, Josh.   I'll attempt to use the "Changing JMS Implementations" link you mentioned above.  I had thought I only had to configure Tomee  itself (with necessary IBM MQ jars, etc) to support the MDB project deployment.  Sounds like this is not possible(?) - i.e., in other words, I *must* bundle the  IBM MQ resource adapter (".rar") file  in an ".ear" containing the MDB project - in order to successfully deploy/run on Tomee server(?).    That is,  I cannot simply deploy the MDB project to Tomee server as a ".war" file (?) - except via your "alternative" suggestion.

Comment: Hi Josh:  just checked (http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-webspheremq.html) and it appears they suggest extracting the contents of the rar file and placing the contents into the tomee/lib folder.   -what are your thoughts on this?  I think this is where I got the idea in the first place :-)

Comment: FWIW - In addition to using IBM MQ resource adapter -  I also want to use CDI annotations to enable the MDB.  I'm yet not precisely clear on what minimal configuration is required to accomplish this.

Comment: IBM provided the  Install-Java-All package if you want individual jar files.  It provides the rar if you want a bundled RA.  I'm sure they would not support you extracting the jars from the rar if they knew this is how you obtained them even if it is likely they are the same.  For JMS you only need `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` (this includes all contents of all separate `com.ibm.mq*.jar` files, and you need the `jms.jar` (this is a JMS-2.0 from Oracle).  If you want to use `.binding` files, then you also need the`fscontext.jar` and `providerutil.jar`.  These are all included in Install-Java-All.

Comment: Thx, Josh..   Problem is that it is not clear from your link how I would effect changing the default RA to IBM MQ RA, for me.  :-/

Comment: I re-read it and I was mistaken, it says if you bundle the rar in a ear that the app in the ear will prefer the bundled rar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Can now deploy working MDB on apache tomee plume 7.x connecting to IBM MQ queue, etc.***

*Love Apache Tomee, so far - but, had to research/google to piece together info from various posts and/or documentation fragments to arrive this poc/solution below... -Not clear whether this solution is recommended(or, ill-advised), but, it is what I'm looking for, in that I did NOT want to include the IBM MQ ".rar" file in my war (or ear) file... -but, rather wanted to deploy to a "pre-configured" (lib, config files) tomee server, etc. (in my case, residing in a Docker container)*

***first placed jar files from "wmq.jmsra-9.1.0.0.rar" into tomee/lib folder***

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1000  464030 Jul  5 21:38 com.ibm.mq.connector.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1000  359297 Jul  5 21:37 com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1000  397171 Jul  5 21:37 com.ibm.mq.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1000 3374322 Jul  5 21:38 com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1000  127566 Jul  5 21:37 com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1000 3999810 Jul  5 21:38 com.ibm.mqjms.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000  1000   792825 Jul  5 21:37 bcpkix-jdk15on.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000  1000  4092400 Jul  5 21:37 bcprov-jdk15on.jar

(note: this seemed adequate for non-MDB, IBM MQ connectivity)
```

***created folder called "ibm_rar" and placed "wmq.jmsra-9.1.0.0.rar" file into it***

```
root@c2865c04748a:/usr/local/tomee# ls -l
total 120
-rw-r--r--. 1 root staff 52711 Jul 10 11:41 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--. 1 root staff  7692 Jul 10 11:22 NOTICE
-rw-r--r--. 1 root staff  7316 Jun 20 19:51 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r--r--. 1 root staff 16722 Jun 20 19:51 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root staff  4096 Oct 15 17:55 bin
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root staff  4096 Oct 15 20:57 conf
drwxr-x---. 3 root root     19 Sep 20 14:33 data
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     58 Oct 15 17:55 ibm_rar  <== contains ".rar" file
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root staff  8192 Oct 15 17:37 lib
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root staff  4096 Oct 16 14:11 logs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root staff  4096 Oct 16 14:11 temp
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root staff  4096 Oct 15 22:37 webapps
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root staff    21 Sep 20 14:33 work
root@c2865c04748a:/usr/local/tomee#
```

***contents of manually created folder - arbitrarily named: "ibm_rar"***

```
root@c2865c04748a:/usr/local/tomee/ibm_rar# ls -l
total 12080
drwxr-x---. 3 root root     4096 Oct 15 17:55 wmq.jmsra-9.1.0.0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1000 1000 12361911 Oct  4 21:11 wmq.jmsra-9.1.0.0.rar
root@c2865c04748a:/usr/local/tomee/ibm_rar# 

(note: appears that on startup, the tomee server explodes the ".rar" file into a corresponding folder)
```

***contents of tomee.xml***

*note "Deployments" entry pointing to location of .rar file*

```
root@c2865c04748a:/usr/local/tomee/conf# cat tomee.xml
<tomee>
    <!-- folder containing resource adapter -->
    <Deployments dir="ibm_rar" />
    <Resource id="wmqRA" type="com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl">
        connectionConcurrency=5
        maxConnections=10
        logWriterEnabled=false
        reconnectionRetryCount=5
        reconnectionRetryInterval=300000
        traceEnabled=false
        traceLevel=3
    </Resource>
    <Resource id="wmqCF" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl">
        TransactionSupport=none
        ResourceAdapter=wmqRA
        HostName=172.17.0.3
        Port=1414
        QueueManager=QM1
        Channel=DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
        TransportType=Client
        UserName=admin
        Password=passw0rd
    </Resource>
    <Resource id="wmqQCF" type="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl">
        TransactionSupport=xa
        ResourceAdapter=wmqRA
    </Resource>
    <Container id="wmq" type="MESSAGE">
        BrokerXmlConfig = 
        ResourceAdapter=wmqRA
        MessageListenerInterface=javax.jms.MessageListener
        ActivationSpecClass=com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl
    </Container>
    <Resource id="devQueue1" type="javax.jms.Queue" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy">
        arbitraryProperties
        baseQueueManagerName=QM1
        baseQueueName=DEV.QUEUE.1
        CCSID=819
        encoding=NATIVE
        expiry=APP
        failIfQuiesce=true
        persistence=APP
        priority=APP
        readAheadClosePolicy=ALL
        targetClient=JMS
    </Resource>
    <Resource id="devQueue2" type="javax.jms.Queue" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy">
        arbitraryProperties
        baseQueueManagerName=QM1
        baseQueueName=DEV.QUEUE.2
        CCSID=819
        encoding=NATIVE
        expiry=APP
        failIfQuiesce=true
        persistence=APP
        priority=APP
        readAheadClosePolicy=ALL
        targetClient=JMS
    </Resource>        
</tomee>
```

***ChatBean.java (MDB)***

```
package org.superbiz.mdb;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    //...annotating "ejb-jar.xml" properties here...
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",propertyValue = "DEV.QUEUE.1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel",propertyValue = "DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName",propertyValue = "172.17.0.3"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port",propertyValue = "1414"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager",propertyValue = "QM1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType",propertyValue = "CLIENT"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "username",propertyValue = "admin"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password",propertyValue = "passw0rd")
}
)
public class ChatBean implements MessageListener {

    @Resource(name = "wmqCF") 
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(name = "devQueue2")
    private Queue answerQueue;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        final TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        final String msg = textMessage.getText();

        System.out.println("\n\n\n..........ChatBean/onMessage..........incoming message: " + String.valueOf(msg));

        respond("...the message received was: " + String.valueOf(msg));

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    }

    private void respond(String text) throws JMSException {

    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        System.out.println("\n\n\n..........ChatBean/respond..........connection object:" + String.valueOf(connection));  
        System.out.println("\n\n\n..........ChatBean/respond..........responding with text:" + String.valueOf(text));    
        connection.start();

        // Create a Session
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(answerQueue);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

        // Create a message
        TextMessage textmessage = session.createTextMessage(text);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n..........ChatBean/respond..........responding with textmessage:" + String.valueOf(textmessage));    
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");            

        // Tell the producer to send the message
        producer.send(textmessage);
    } finally {
        // Clean up
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleMDB</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd.HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>        

    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>10</release>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>/usr/local/jdkv10/bin/javac</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Tomee-Application-Version>${project.version}-${timestamp}</Tomee-Application-Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***war file copied/deployed to tomee/webapps folder***

```
root@c2865c04748a:/usr/local/tomee/webapps# ls -l
total 1668
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root staff    4096 Sep 20 14:18 ROOT
drwxr-x---.  4 root root       53 Oct 15 22:37 SimpleMDB
-rw-rw-r--.  1 1000  1000 1694696 Oct 15 22:36 SimpleMDB.war
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root staff    4096 Sep 20 14:18 docs
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root staff      82 Sep 20 14:18 host-manager
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root staff    4096 Sep 20 14:18 manager
root@c2865c04748a:/usr/local/tomee/webapps# 

(tomee server explodes into corresponding folder on startup)
```

Comment: Re: "first placed jar files from "wmq.jmsra-9.1.0.0.rar" into tomee/lib folder", you would be better to get the "Java-All" package and include the `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`, it includes all the classes in the `com.ibm.mq.*.jar` files that you mention.  You only the the `bc*.jar` files if you place to use IBM MQ AMS functionality, this requires IBM MQ Advanced entitlement (more cost) on the queue manager end, if you are not using it those are not required.

Comment: If it expands the rar automatically and the MDB uses the classes from there, I wonder why you can not also reference the classes from the rar in the non-MDB components?

Comment: Could be that just the expanded .rar will provide all needs.  But, haven't tested that yet (this is an admittedly primitive poc).  In the meantime, I'll try using just the "allclient.jar" in place of the multiple .rar jars.  Regarding the two bc*.jar's - early on it seemed they were required to compile and/or run some basic non-MDB app that required IBM MQ connectivity.   I'll be revisiting to see if still true.  The big win for me is the ability to essentially "drop in" the ".rar" file for IBM/MQ MDB support.   -In any case, thx again for your ongoing feed back, JoshMc!   :-)

Comment: No problem.  Probably will help me out some day that you figure this out for when an app wants to ask me how to use TomEE with IBM MQ in the future :)

Comment: FWIW - checked and seems - in addition to the "exploded" .rar (e.g., tomee/ibm_rar) folder - that the ".rar" jar files still must be copied to the tomee/lib folder, as per Apache Tomee documentation (except - in the case of my poc app - the bc.*.jars...i.e., disabling these seems to have no ill effect).   Also, it appears the com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar is not sufficient to replace the ".rar" jar files in the tomee/lib folder.

Comment: Extract *.rar with libs into your `tomee\lib` using [this instruction](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031630_.htm)